# Spring Data JPA Like or Containing

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, sql-like

I'm messing with Spring Boot Data JPA and, reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), I got confused. Whats the difference?

What I understood is, the "Like" operator makes SQL without the "%" surrounding my String (where name like 'String') and the "Containing" operator makes SQL with the "%" surrounding my String (where name like '%String%'). Am I wrong?

I used the "Like" operator and he works fine in situations where the "%" is required in both sides so, I'm really confused!

Comment: Can you find abcStringabc with like statement?

Comment: That's what makes me confused. I never used "Containing", just "Like" and I have operations that need "%" in both sides, so yes! My application can find "abcStringabc" with "Like" operator. So, with that in mind, whats the difference? Or I'm cursed and that's not the spectated thing to happen? (I'm using Spring Boot Data 1.5.2 btw)

Comment: I guess you are looking the latest documentation but old version does not have any information about Containing.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that you can emulate a `containing` with a `like`.

The differences are:

- you have to enclose your search string with wildcards yourself when using like.
- you can have wildcards not only at the beginning or end but also in the middle, multiple wildcards in the middle and different wildcards like `_` which matches a single character.
- a final subtile difference is that `containing` will escape wildcards contained in your search argument, which like would not. So when searching for `abc%def` the two behave differently

  ```
                  | containing     | like (with additional `%` around the searchstring)
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  123abc%def456   | matches        | matches
  123abcXYZdef456 | does not match | matches
  ```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!